# Angular: HostListener window:beforeunload is not working when user closes the browser

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) beforeUnloadHandler(event: Event) {
    if (this.msgService.istrue) {
      Connect.handleEnd();
    }
  }
```

Here, the beforeunload is working perfectly fine for page reload but once the user closes the tab the listener is getting called but it is not triggering the endpoints that I need to execute.
But if I add a confirm event then the endpoints are getting executed and working fine as shown below. But I dont want to use these confirm popups. Can someone tell me what is the issue on the above code? For reload it works but not for broswer closing?

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) beforeUnloadHandler(event: Event) {
    confirm("you want to close the browser?");
    if (this.msgService.isEscalation) {
      Connect.handleEnd();
    }
    event.returnValue = false;
  }
```

Comment: There is no guarantee any async call will work on `beforeunload`.

Comment: How to handle this situation then? @MatthieuRiegler

Answer (score 2):

The browser will cancel (or not even allow to start) any connection made during `beforeunload`  event...

You can, however, use the [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) method that sends a request that does not accept any response.

> This method is intended for analytics and diagnostics code to send data to a server.
>
> A problem with sending analytics is that a site often wants to send analytics when the user has finished with a page: for example, when the user navigates to another page. In this situation the browser may be about to unload the page, and in that case the browser may choose not to send asynchronous XMLHttpRequest requests.